# how to use svm in Weka Classsifier?

Tags: weka, svm

I am trying to use SVM classifier in Weka. I downloaded weka-3-7-13 version. When i click on the classifier tab, SVM is not in the list.

How to use SVM in this tool? Please help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 16):

In Weka (GUI) go to Tools -> PackageManager and install LibSVM/LibLinear (both are SVM).

One more implementation of SVM is 'SMO' which is in Classify -> Classifier -> Functions. (if not listed then install as mentioned above)

Alternatively you can use .jar files of these algorithms and use through your java code.

Answer (score 2):

SVM classes are not integrated with the WEKA vanilla. you have to add [LIBSVM](https://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM) library (jar file ) manually into your project to get SVM classifiers

Comment: Thank you..  i try weka 3-6-10 . When i classify using libSVM  there is an error " libsvm classes are not in classpath" . how to solve this ?

Comment: if you using eclipses copy the jar file to project folder and right click on the jar --> build path --> add to build path.  if you find the answer is correct . please consider accept it for future viewers